# Proper resources in scripture of side effects of Nav Grah mantra

Tags: mantras, astrology, navagraha

Some people say that if Nav Grah beej mantras are not chanted properly then they have side effects as well.

Questions:

- Which texts in ancient scripture (shastras) describe the beej mantras of Grahas and their methodology of chanting?
- Which text describes bad effects of Nav Grah beej mantra?

Again I am emphasizing on proper description in scripture not by some astrologers.

Comment: The Beeja mantras are probably all from Tantras. Like Graha Yamala etc. Very hard to find these Tantras these days online or otherwise.

Comment: Is there any side effects of chanting this beej mantra? I have no knowledge. But if hreem and shreem are of mantras of deities they how chanting "om hrim shrim shukray namah" create problem?

Comment: Probably the problem is that these mantras are to be chanted  a fixed thousands number of times within a stipulated number of days. I Failing to do so makes the grahas angry. I will give you a link when I find it.